# Regex prefix lookaround not working in coldfusion 10

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am using `reMatch` to get the matched substring from a list. But when I am using prefix lookaround then I am getting error.

> Sequence (?<...) not recognized

**Code:**

```
<cfset local.path = "schedule.category.classes.name,schedule.category.classes.id">
<cfset local.regex = "(?<=schedule.category.classes.)[a-zA-Z0-9_]*?(?=,|$)">
<cfset local.output = reMatch(local.regex, local.path)>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe this article about coldfusion regex look arounds will be helpful. http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/regular-expressions-in-coldfusion-part_26.html?m=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the bit about reading the docs ;-) - [Regular expression syntax - Using special characters](http://Regularexpressionsyntax-Usingspecialcharacters) - Look behinds & arounds are not supported in CFML's flavour of regex (which is long-dead [Apache ORO](http://attic.apache.org/projects/jakarta-oro.html)).

However it's easy enough to use java's regex implementation instead, which *does* support look-behinds: [java.util.regex.Pattern - Special constructs (named-capturing and non-capturing)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special).

I have written two parts of a three part series on using Java regexes in CFML: "[Regular expressions in CFML (part 9: Java support for regular expressions (1/3))](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/03/regular-expressions-in-coldfusion-part.html)". I must get back to doing part 3 at some point, but what you need is in the first coupla parts anyhow.

Ben Nadel also writes extensively on using Java regexes in CFML. Just do a quick google if you get stuck having looked @ my notes (but let me know where you get stuck if you do, so I can revisit my wording!).

Comment: Lookaheads are supported by ColdFusion regexes, but lookbehinds are not. You can also, if you're on a Windows box running IIS, use .Net regular expressions.

Comment: As a bonus, even with the overhead, you'll find that the java regex engine is faster than ColdFusion. 
Also, you should feel blessed that Adam is answering CF questions when he is a full time PHP dev now.

Comment: It's only cos I'm not good enough @ PHP yet to help out there. Plus it's difficult to get an answer in quick enough with the PHP ones!

Answer (score 1):

Look-behinds are not available in Coldfusion regex patterns. Instead of [`reMatch`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e35.html), you can use [`REReplace`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e98.html) to remove everything around the string you need to obtain:

```
<cfset local.path = "schedule.category.classes.name,schedule.category.classes.id">
<cfset local.regex = "schedule\.category\.classes\.([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).*$">
<cfset local.output = REReplace(local.path,local.regex,"\1")>
```